# How to find out if an attribute is in the table for a user?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase table where I need to find out if an attribute exists in the table for a particular user.  Table is structured like this:

```
Users
-Lf9xUh53VeL4OLlwqQo 
   username: "my@test.com"
   price:    "$100"
   special:  "No"

-L12345ff322223345fd 
   username: "my2@test.com"
   special:  "No"
```

I need to find out if the "price" has been added for a specific user.  Can't seem to figure that one out!

In swift I need something like:

```
        self.ref?.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: username.text!).observe(.value, with: { (snapShot) in
        if (snapShot.value! is NSNull) {
            print("nothing found")
        } else {
            print("found it!")
            print(snapShot)

            let snapShotValue = snapShot.value as! [String:[String:Any]]
                Array(snapShotValue.values).forEach { // error here if it doesn't exist
                let price = $0["price"] as! String
                self.userPrice.text = price
            }}
        })
```

But if the price doesn't exist I'm getting an error.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `as?` instead of `as!`

```
if let price = $0["price"] as? String {
  print(price)
}
else {
   print("No price")
}
```

Or shortly

```
self.userPrice.text = ($0["price"] as? String) ?? "No price"
```